# Dockerfile cmd returns Yarn integrity error but Docker run works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, yarnpkg

I'm trying to get a Rails 6 application to run in Docker.  When the command rails server is executed from the dockerfile, I get an error.

```
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | warning Integrity check: System parameters don't match
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | error Integrity check failed
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | error Found 1 errors.
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | 
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | 
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | ========================================
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 |   Your Yarn packages are out of date!
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 |   Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | ========================================
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | 
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | 
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | To disable this check, please change `check_yarn_integrity`
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | to `false` in your webpacker config file (config/webpacker.yml).
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | 
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | 
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | yarn check v1.16.0
remote: web_1_a59d968487d2 | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check for documentation about this command.
```

In my config/webpacker.yml file I have this line:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  check_yarn_integrity: false
```

In my config/environments/development.rb:

```
  config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false
```

I am also building my node_modules as part of the docker setup (Dockerfile):

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install apt-transport-https
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

COPY . /myapp
RUN rm -Rf node_modules/
RUN rm yarn.lock
RUN yarn install

ENV RAILS_ENV=development
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Running `docker-compose run web rails s -b 0.0.0.0` works.

Running `docker-compose up --build web` returns the error.

Comment: see how he did it https://shivab.com/blog/docker/2019/01/15/dockerization-of-rails-6-app/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compare your `Dockerfile`+`docker-compose.yml` with [this one](https://gist.github.com/erdostom/5dd400cbba17d44b52b2f74b038fcb85) and see if there is nay difference (like using `RUN yarn install --check-files`) which would make the error message disappear.

Another example ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/soulmates-ai/docker-rails-demo/blob/33771771a0d3b0797e49ef2c181b3ff397646f3a/Dockerfile)+[`docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/soulmates-ai/docker-rails-demo/blob/33771771a0d3b0797e49ef2c181b3ff397646f3a/docker-compose.yml)) is used in "**[Running a Rails app with Webpacker and Docker](https://medium.com/@dirkdk/running-a-rails-app-with-webpacker-and-docker-8d29153d3446)**" from **[Dirk de Kok](https://twitter.com/dirkdk)**

In both instances, the application is started with `docker-compose up`.
And they have followed, as you have, the recommendations of [`rails/webpacker` issue 1568](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1568#issuecomment-459995382) (regarding `config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false` in  `config/environments/development.rb`)

Comment: You are missing a hyphen in docker compose, and it wanted me to include 6 characters to edit.  I couldn't find anything else to make the answer better, so I was wondering if you could add the hyphen. `docker-compose`

Comment: @AndyGauge Sure, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It worked today.  No code was changed, it just decided to work.  I tried running docker-compose run web rm -rf / to start over, but it ignored that command then started working.  C'est la vie.  @vonc thanks for the effort, I'll reward you.

Edit: It returned.  This time I fixed it using

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Warning: This destroys all your containers.  Do not use this if you have data inside your volumes.

The cause of the problem was experimenting with creating a Dockerfile and the compose was not clearing out a layer of the volume.  `docker-compose run` is different than `docker-compose up` because `run` creates a new layer on top of the docker volume to execute the command, essentially creating a new container.  Docker itself was failing to apply the changes to an old layer.

Answer (score 3):

> making `config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false` is not a good idea.

It occurs due to version incompatibility.

try

```sh
rails webpacker:install
```

It should solve your problem.

---

if not try

```sh
$ rm yarn.lock
$ yarn cache clean
$ yarn install
```

Comment: Yeah I was at wits end, trying to figure out what was going on, but it had nothing to do with rails and yarn, it was a bug in docker.  I was way past those steps by the tme I posted to SO.  I do hope this helps somebody who is having a similar problem.